# Unable to navigate to other screen in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am navigating to third screen from second screen but it is showing an error Application tried to push a nil view controller on target. Here is the below code am using to navigate,

```
 if (appDelegate.thirdViewController == nil) {
    ThirdViewController *sThirdViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
    [appDelegate setThirdViewController:sThirdViewController];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:appDelegate.thirdViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like AppDelegate has no reference,

did you wrote appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

check once..